# Retrieve Files from remote server based on yesterday's date

Tags: php

I need to modify this script to retrieve only the files with yesterday's date. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
$username = 'XXXXXX';
$password = 'XXXXXX';
$ftp_server = 'data.mywebsite.com';

 $conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
if(ftp_login($conn, $username, $password))
{
    echo 'Logged in';
}
else
{
    echo 'FTP Error:Could not log in to '.$ftp_server;
    exit();
}
ftp_pasv ($conn, true);
if (ftp_chdir($conn, "../Photos/Hi-res")) {
    echo "Current FTP directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn) . "\n";
} else { 
    echo "Couldn't change to Photos directory\n";
}

$list = ftp_nlist($conn, '.');
function is_img($file) {
    if(preg_match('/.*\.png/', $file))
    {
        return preg_match('/.*\.png/', $file) > 0;
    }
    if(preg_match('/.*\.jpg/', $file))
    {
        return preg_match('/.*\.jpg/', $file) > 0;
    }
    if(preg_match('/.*\.gif/', $file))
    {
        return preg_match('/.*\.gif/', $file) > 0;
    }
}

$filtered = array_filter($list, is_img);
foreach($filtered as $img) {
    if (ftp_get($conn, $img, $img, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Successfully written to $img\n";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem\n";
    }
}
ftp_close($conn);
```

When I run the script, it is grabbing all files not already on my server which is not what I want. I just want it to grab all the files with yesterdays date.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution for you, please note that this will not take the server timezone differences or other pitfalls into account when comparing the mtimes.

The main change is that the is_img function have been renamed and extended with ftp_mdtm() for each file.

```
$username = 'XXXXXX';
$password = 'XXXXXX';
$ftp_server = 'data.mywebsite.com';
$now = time();

 $conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
if(ftp_login($conn, $username, $password))
{
    echo 'Logged in';
}
else
{
    echo 'FTP Error:Could not log in to '.$ftp_server;
    exit();
}
ftp_pasv ($conn, true);
if (ftp_chdir($conn, "../Photos/Hi-res")) {
    echo "Current FTP directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't change to Photos directory\n";
}

$list = ftp_nlist($conn, '.');
function is_for_download($file) {
    $is_img = false;

    if(preg_match('/.*\.png/', $file))
    {
        $is_img = preg_match('/.*\.png/', $file) > 0;
    }
    if(preg_match('/.*\.jpg/', $file))
    {
        $is_img = preg_match('/.*\.jpg/', $file) > 0;
    }
    if(preg_match('/.*\.gif/', $file))
    {
        $is_img = preg_match('/.*\.gif/', $file) > 0;
    }

    if (!$is_img) {
        return false;
    }

    global $conn;
    global $now;

    $yesterday_start = strtotime('yesterday midnight', $now);
    $yesterday_end = strtotime('yesterday midnight + 24 hours', $now);
    $mtime = ftp_mdtm($conn, $file);

    if ($yesterday_start <= $mtime && $mtime <= $yesterday_end) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$filtered = array_filter($list, 'is_for_download');
foreach($filtered as $img) {
    if (ftp_get($conn, $img, $img, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Successfully written to $img\n";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem\n";
    }
}
ftp_close($conn);
```